# Which method of framing a soffit around rectangular ductwork maximizes ceiling height?

Tags: framing, soffit

I need to put a soffit around 18"(W) x 8"(H) x 23'(L) rectangular HVAC ductwork in my basement and I am very near to the minimal code requirements for ceiling height for obstructions before adding a soffit.

If possible, the ideal solution would result in a soffit that is up to code (International Residential Code), structurally sound, and takes up less than 1 inch of additional space below the ducts. The one inch requirement is a finished height that includes 1/2" drywall or another material approved for fireblocking that would result in a nice finish. The soffit framing can extend horizontally as far as needed without creating any issues.

If my request of one inch or less in lost height is not possible, then I am still interested methods that minimize height loss and lead to a code-approved and structurally sound soffit.

Comment: What is the width of the duct?  Drywall by itself does perfectly fine over a 24-inch span.

Comment: So are you recommending: 1.) Build an 8" mini-wall that runs the full length of the duct and hangs from the ceiling (using metal studs would help keep the wall straight, would 2 1/2" metal studs be too flimsy?), 2.) Put a furring strip on the wall in between the wall and the duct and have the bottom of the furring strip flush with the bottom of the duct, 3.) Cut the drywall to size and attach the drywall parallel to the bottom of the duct and fasten using drywall screws to the bottom plate of the miniwall and the bottom of the furring strip. Or, is there another method that is better?

Comment: Not recommending anything yet.  But your idea sounds pretty good.  Why are you looking at metal studs?  Wood is my preference and I have no experience with steel studs.  Regardless, you want to avoid attaching the "bottom plate" to the bottoms of the studs with nails.  They'll just pull straight out.  I'll have to sketch it out as soon as I have your layout in my head.  How far from the wall are you and how much room do you have to work with on the other side?

Comment: I like metal studs for hanging drywall because they are lightweight for working overhead and do not warp like wood often does when exposed to different conditions. The straightness of the metal studs makes drywalling go smooth without having to dig through 20 pieces of lumber just to find 2 that are straight and true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use wood for everything.  This is how I would put it together with 2x4s.  Personally, I think 2x4s are overkill for this, but that's just me.  I suggest using screws as your fasteners, and with screws your "bottom plate" is probably sound.  Screws will be fine in tension.  If you are using nails, I'd stick to the sketch so that your nails are loaded in shear.

The main code issue you are going to be dealing with here is fireblocking.  You have this open plenum that connects all the joist cavities which allows fire to spread quickly across the joists.  You'll want to stuff insulation in areas that will prevent airflow from one joist (and wall) cavity to another.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Paul. I just realized that there is only about a quarter inch between the duct and the wall. Do you have any additional suggestions for securing the portion of the drywall that touches the wall?

Comment: @statueuphemism I'd still put a furring strip in as a guide, but drive the screws in at an angle to catch the studs.  These alone won't be sufficient to hold the sheetrock up permanently, but it will hold it in place while you put the wall sheetrock up.  Once you have the wall board up (put it in after the soffit sheetrock) and the gap is filled with mud and the corner has been taped, then the soffit sheetrock will be secure.  It probably wouldn't hurt to throw in some adhesive or gap-filler to bond the sheetrock to the duct.

Comment: @statueuphemism  Another idea:  instead of a continuous furring strip, place 2x4  blocking between the studs, offset to touch the duct.  A bit more work, but you'll be able to place sheetrock screws every 6-in or whatever is required for ceilings..

Comment: @statueuphemism  ...or better yet, use the 2x4 blocking *and* the furring strip.  That way you meet your fireblock requirement and sheetrock fastener spacing.

Comment: @statueuphemism  another thought:  Put the tapered edge against the wall.    The screws driven at an angle won't blow out as easily and you don't have to worry too much about getting the heads below flush because you'll be filling the taper with mud.